# Compare two String[] arrays and print out the strings which differ

Tags: java, arrays

I've got a list of all the file names in a folder and a list of files which have been manually "checked" by a developer. How would I go about comparing the two arrays such that we print out only those which are not contained in the master list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        String[] list = {"my_purchases", "my_reservation_history", "my_reservations", "my_sales", "my_wallet", "notifications", "order_confirmation", "payment", "payment_methods", "pricing", "privacy", "privacy_policy", "profile_menu", "ratings", "register", "reviews", "search_listings", "search_listings_forms", "submit_listing", "submit_listing_forms", "terms_of_service", "transaction_history", "trust_verification", "unsubscribe", "user", "verify_email", "verify_shipping", "404", "account_menu", "auth", "base", "dashboard_base", "dashboard_menu", "fiveohthree", "footer", "header", "header_menu", "listings_menu", "main_searchbar", "primary_navbar"};
        String[] checked = {"404", "account_menu", "auth", "base", "dashboard_base", "dashboard_menu", "fiveohthree", "footer", "header", "header_menu", "listings_menu"};

        ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(int i = 0; i < checked.length; i++)
                {
                    if(!Arrays.asList(list).contains(checked[i]))
                    ar.add(checked[i]);
                }
    }
```

Comment: If I'm understanding the question correctly, I would use nested loops and store the names not contained in a new array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your loop to :

```
ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i = 0; i < checked.length; i++) {
      if(!Arrays.asList(list).contains(checked[i]))
      ar.add(checked[i]);
}
```

`ArrayList` `ar` should be outside of the **for** loop. Otherwise `ar` will be created every time when element of `checked` array exists in `list`.

**Edit:**

```
if(!Arrays.asList(list).contains(checked))
```

With this statement you are checking whether the `checked` reference is not the element of `list`. It should be `checked[i]` to check whether the element of `checked` exists in `list` or not.

If you want to print elements in `list` that are not in `checked`. Then use :

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if(!Arrays.asList(checked).contains(list[i]))
      ar.add(list[i]);
}
System.out.println(ar);
```

Comment: Thanks but I get a compilation error when printing. See my updated question.

Comment: Just use `System.out.println(ar)` to print `ar`. Internally `toString()` will be invoked on `ar`.

Comment: Thanks, you can see it here: http://ideone.com/AigDCH. Doesn't seem to print anything out.

Comment: Because all the elements of `checked` are exists in `list`. first check this.

Comment: Ah I see. But I wanted to print out the elements that do not exist. I think I solved it. See my updated answer.

Comment: what you want exactly. Are you want to pint the elements of `list` which are not exists in `checked`.

Comment: Yes. I want to print elements in list that are not in checked. These are the remaining tasks to be worked on.

Comment: But see your question what you mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

Your updated solution seems kind of odd to me, not sure why you would add list[i] to the result list.  Generally this sounds like something hashsets are made for:

```
String[] list = { "my_purchases", "my_reservation_history","my_reservations","my_sales", "my_wallet", "notifications", "order_confirmation", "payment", "payment_methods", "pricing", "privacy", "privacy_policy", "profile_menu", "ratings", "register", "reviews", "search_listings", "search_listings_forms", "submit_listing", "submit_listing_forms", "terms_of_service", "transaction_history", "trust_verification", "unsubscribe", "user", "verify_email", "verify_shipping", "404", "account_menu", "auth", "base", "dashboard_base", "dashboard_menu", "fiveohthree", "footer", "header", "header_menu", "listings_menu", "main_searchbar", "primary_navbar"};
String[] checked = { "404", "account_menu", "auth", "base", "dashboard_base", "dashboard_menu", "fiveohthree", "footer", "header", "header_menu", "listings_menu"};

HashSet<String> s1 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(checked));
s1.removeAll(Arrays.asList(list));
System.out.println(s1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (String s: checked) {      // go through all in second list
    if (! list.contains(s)) {  // if string not in master list
        System.out.println(s); // print that string
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think your code has some errors:

- s1 is not defined
- ar is not defined
- you mean to use Arrays.toString instead of Array.toString

So I fixed your code (using Java 8) and it should work like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    String[] list = {"my_purchases", "my_reservation_history", "my_reservations", "my_sales", "my_wallet", "notifications", "order_confirmation", "payment", "payment_methods", "pricing", "privacy", "privacy_policy", "profile_menu", "ratings", "register", "reviews", "search_listings", "search_listings_forms", "submit_listing", "submit_listing_forms", "terms_of_service", "transaction_history", "trust_verification", "unsubscribe", "user", "verify_email", "verify_shipping", "404", "account_menu", "auth", "base", "dashboard_base", "dashboard_menu", "fiveohthree", "footer", "header", "header_menu", "listings_menu", "main_searchbar", "primary_navbar"};
    String[] checked = {"404", "account_menu", "auth", "base", "dashboard_base", "dashboard_menu", "fiveohthree", "footer", "header", "header_menu", "listings_menu"};

    final List<String> result = Stream.of(list)
            .filter(listEntry -> Stream.of(checked)
                    .filter(checkedEntry -> checkedEntry.equals(listEntry)).findFirst().orElse(null) == null)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

If you don't want to use Java 8, you have to replace the usage of Streams and filters and collect with the appropriate functions in Java 7 (see e.g., Satya's post).

Anyways, I should mention that there are better (regarding performance) implementations to solve your problem, e.g.,

- you could sort your lists prior to searching for duplicates,
- you could use, e.g., hash-based implementations to increase the speed when searching for duplicates,
- you could move the code outside of the inner loop,
- and many more